# How can I clear input text in bootstrap -UPDATED

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a simple modal in bootstrap 3.0.2 and it has a 2 simple input type="text" I would like to clear it. I have seen example but they are for bootstrap 2 and don't work with my modal. Does any one know how to clear or reset this input text inside a modal when I click on the "reset" button.

-Thank you in advance.

Update: after using @davethecoder solution works like a charm, I still need help clearing 1 of the input text its under the date class:

```
 <input id="#item" type="text" class="date-picker form-control" />
```

Any chance anyone knows how to clear this one? 
-Thank you for helping me.

Comment: add your code please...

Comment: fiddle will help you , put it in your question

Comment: clear the class form-control

Comment: question of how do i clear a form does not require code or a fiddle, as this is not a problem / error when clearing a form, but simply a question asking how do you clear a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twitter bootstrap is a CSS framework for modelling response web layouts.   If you are using jquery,  the code to clear an element is  `$("#itemid").val('');`

easiest would be to give each item a class, and set this value based on class,   or as an alternative, you can loop through items of specific formid and reset to clear that way.   Personally I would just do this class based, as this will essentially have the loop code per item, within the jquery framework.

I mentioned jquery here, because you had a jquery tag

Comment: beautiful works like a charm, but it doesn't clear 1 of the input text because its under the date class:  <input id="#item" type="text"  class="date-picker form-control" />  Any chance you know how to clear it up? Thanks.

Comment: add the extra class,   so you have class="date clear", will still pick it up, you would then clear all with class of clear  $(".clear").val('');

Comment: Thank you so Much, Took me awhile to figure it out but it worked!!! You sir are a coding wizard. Thank you so much for your patience and for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

Oh,just I found that the attribute id of your input element contains `'#'`,it may lead to some unknown mistake. It is best to remove the `'#'` on your `<input>`.
If you are using jQuery, just use a function call like this to clear input:

```
$('#item').val('');
```

If you're not using jQuery, just use Javascript function like this:

```
document.getelementById('item').value = "";
```